# the deafult( Apache) compression code is recognized but the cashing code not when I run GoogleInsights?

Tags: .htaccess

I have pasted this code :

## BEGIN Leverage Browser Caching Headers

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on  


    # Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"


    # cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thanks Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
        ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest "access plus 0 seconds"


    # Your document html
        ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"


    # Data
        ExpiresByType text/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/xml "access plus 0 seconds"
        ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 0 seconds"


    # Feed
        ExpiresByType application/rss+xml "access plus 1 hour"
        ExpiresByType application/atom+xml "access plus 1 hour"


    # Favicon (cannot be renamed)
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 week"
        ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 1 week"  
        ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 week"


    # Media: images, video, audio
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/ogg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType audio/ogg "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/mp4 "access plus 1 month"
        ExpiresByType video/webm "access plus 1 month"


    # HTC files (css3pie)
        ExpiresByType text/x-component "access plus 1 month"


    # Add correct content-type for fonts
        AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
        AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf
        AddType application/x-font-opentype .otf
        AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
        AddType image/svg+xml .svg


    # Compress compressible fonts
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf application/x-font-opentype image/svg+xml


    # Add a far future Expires header for fonts
        ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-opentype "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access plus 1 year" 


    # CSS and JavaScript
        ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 year"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 year"  
        ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"


    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

## END Leverage Browser Caching Headers

## BEGIN Enable Gzip

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

## Or, compress certain file types by extension:

```
<files *.html>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
```

## END Enable Gzip

## BEGIN WordPress

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

when I run GoogleInsights anlayze tool I see that de  compression(code) is recognized  but  the browser cashing code is not been recognized !!!  I don't understand why because this  is default code (for Apache server)which been advised? my website is http://computertechnet.nl .
how I can solve this problem ?
thanks 
johannes

Answer (score 0):

This is a non-issue. When I run your site through Google Page Insights, it does flag "Leverage browser caching" under the "Consider Fixing" section, but when I expand this I see the following:

> Leverage browser caching
>
> **Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for static resources instructs the browser to load previously downloaded
>   resources from local disk rather than over the network.**
>
> Leverage browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/…ps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&ver=4.3.1
>   (30 minutes)

In other words everything hosted on your site is cached correctly, but a bit of Javascript you pull in from another site (Google ironically enough!) is only being cached for 30 mins and Google Page Insights thinks that's not long enough.

So everything else on your site is being cached. If it wasn't it would be flagged under the "Should Fix" section. So don't worry about this.

Yes it's annoying that Google Page Insights doesn't recognise that 1) This is an external resource and 2) It's a Google external resource so they should not flag it.

I suspect you're concentrating too much on the headline number (60/100) but that's mainly caused by the fact that your server is too slow (3 seconds to respond), you have a, quick frankly, ridiculous 22 different css stylesheets (adding another 3 seconds to load time) and you have a 1.5Mb image.

See here:
http://www.webpagetest.org/result/151126_DX_17W7/

Websites should load in under 2 seconds - ideally in under 100ms to be completely unnoticeable to users but that's pretty much impossible to achieve. Your website takes at least 9 seconds.

Comment: 1- how I can solve server problem because it is from my provider and not of me?                2-how I can solve 22 css stylsheets problems?     3- do I have to compress images with plug in or in php(I see plug ins causing delay for loading in GTmetrics)?    4- how I can solve google map problem?  can you explain to me very shortly.                  thanks very much johannes

Comment: 1 ask your provider. 2. Combine them or remove the ones you don't need. 3. Google "optimise JPEG" 4. You don't need to - the tool is just flagging something that isn't really a problem and you have no control over anyway. These tools are not perfect and are meant to be guidelines not gospel. Though to be honest I couldn't find a map on your home page so not sure why you are even loading this JavaScript.